# Can you install a python file from git as a module?

Tags: python

I am currently interested in installing the following git repository:
https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python/tree/master/examples/xor.

It contains a file called visualize.py and I would love to just install and use it as a module (e.g. numpy). However, I'm not sure how if it is possible to do this and was, therefore, hoping anyone could clarify this for me.

I have tried:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python/tree/master/examples/xor
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
I was able to clone the entire repo:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python.git
```

Does this mean I should be able to use all the files available in this repository as a module or is there something I'm still missing? I still cannot use **visualize** as a module. Thanks!

Comment: I don’t think this can be done. pip installs packages, not modules.

Comment: Does this mean I will have to put the visualize file in my local directory when working on projects every time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to clone the library to the same directory, you can simply `import` the python file without pip installing as module.

For instance if the file is called myFile.py, you can call the following and the entire file is executed and functions within can be used.

```
import myFile
```

Answer (score 0):

1- open directory with modules
example : c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
2-New python file created
example : visualize.py
3- save the python file.